# Can a JavaScript function check if its being run on a Web Worker thread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I'm writing a javascript function and would like to execute unique behaviour if it is being called on a Web Worker.

Without adding a hint to the signature of the function to be passed in by the caller, is there a way to test for this within the function itself?  i.e.:

```
function foo() {
    var is_being_run_on_web_worker = ???;
    if (is_being_run_on_web_worker) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can test for the typical APIs that are apparent in a WebWorker environment (like `importScripts`, no `window` and no DOM), but you can never be sure what exactly it is.

Comment: Why would you want that? A function's behaviour should not depend on its environment. Please tell us what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: In cordova (toolkit for building hybrid mobile apps), we are polyfilling some typical browser behavior using a platform native<->javascript bridge.  We are considering options for polyfills used inside Web Workers, which may involve alternative implementations, since the bridge is not safe to use on more than one thread.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lots of stuff is normally not accessible from a web worker, like the window object. You could check if window is undefined. Of course, someone could overwrite the window object in the scope, so this in not very robust.

Comment: That was our current strategy, thanks.  I was wondering if there was anything more robust.